# How to reload a GET request in created . Vue.js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, get, reload

i am getting the data from my rails API backend and what i want to do is reload that get request every 15s , so if something changes on a backend ( for example i make a post request to my backend in another route)  it reloads and gets the current data .

My created :

```
created() {


    if (!localStorage.signedIn) {
      this.$router.replace("/");
    } else {
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/records")
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.records.splice(0, this.records.length - 1, ...response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/templates")
        .then(response => {
          this.templates = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
      this.$http.secured
        .get("/api/v1/data")
        .then(response => {
          this.datas = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => this.setError(error, "Something went wrong"));
    }
  },
```

Could you help me with implementing a setInterval to my get requests?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to use the setInterval, like:

```js
mounted() {
    this.intervalData = setInterval(this.getdata, 15000)
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalData)
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {}
  },
```

2. More smart solution could be: use POST request in nuxt proxy server or in your backend, like axios.post('/data', payload) and connect the websockets, you can use [pusher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pusher) for that. The final logic is: user add some data => post to server => server emits the websockets event => vuex listen to the event and the data will be reactive in all tabs.